# Return value in If-else statement - C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, return-value

The below code prints:

```
5
```

Why does it print 5? Also if it returns 5 why it doesn't print "James"? I do not understand the below code. If I delete the else word it prints -1. However shouldn't it return a default value?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int fonk()
{
    int a = 5, b = 3;
    int c = a*b;
    if(c >10)
    {
        if( a<b && a >0)
        {   cout <<"James";
        return a;
        }

        else if(b<0)
        {
            return b;
        }

    }
    else return -1;

}

int main()
{
    int x = fonk();
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: That code should never be returning 5. I would check to make sure you do not have any compiler errors that are preventing the application from being recompiled to make sure you are actually starting the right executable.

Comment: What compiler?  For me, it most definitely does not print or return 5...

Comment: this code cannot be compiled, as not all path returns values

Comment: It is g++. I'm really confused.

Comment: To compile this code, you would need to add an else case with no condition after your else if(b<0) condition.

Comment: @IlyaBursov, Why it can't?

Comment: @soon because `not all control paths return value` error which will be given by most (or even all) c++ compilers

Comment: @IlyaBursov Many compilers require you to have compiler flags before that warning/error appears, and will allow this to compile without those...

Comment: @IlyaBursov, Don't remember if the Standard requires that, so, I'm looking in it. Can you give me a paragraph number, please?

Comment: @IlyaBursov, I've found a quote about UB: _"[n3337:6.6.3.2]: Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function."_ but this is well-formed program, so, compiler should pass this code.

Comment: @soon thank you for standard, it is really surprise for me that standard allows such things, maybe first chapter in all books should be "how to enable all errors/warnings before you write 1st line of code" :)

Comment: @IlyaBursov: it's because occasionally someone will want to write code like `if (condition) return 1 else throw_exception();`. The compiler doesn't know that `throw_exception()` doesn't return (although some compilers let you declare that it doesn't). It would be a nuisance to have to write `return 0;` at the end of that function just to shut up an error about how allegedly there's a path that doesn't return. Basically, C++ prioritizes correct code being sensible, over incorrect code giving useful errors...

Comment: @SteveJessop yeap, I forgot about such possibility, and it is not java where you have to declare throws, it is c++ where you can shoot your leg :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are hitting *undefined behaviour*. Your function actually doesn't `return` anything! Look at each condition:

- `c>10`? yes.
- `a<b && a >0`? no.
- `b<0`? no.

So you never hit any of the `return`s. This means absolutely anything could happen in your program. In your case, it seems to just so happen that `5` is stored where the program expects a `return` value.

Answer (score 5):

So the first two lines of fonk delcare the following values:

```
int a = 5, b = 3, c = a *b;
```

So `a` is 5, `b` is 3 and `c` is 15.

```
if(c >10)
```

15 is greater than 10.

```
    if( a<b && a >0)
```

this is not true, so the James/return a branch is not executed.

```
    else if(b<0)
```

b is 3, which is >= 0, so the return b statement is not executed.

```
else
```

this statement refers to "c > 10", the c > 10 was true, so this else clause is not executed.

```
}
```

your function ends without returning anything, this invokes "Undefined Behavior".

Solutions: Remove the 'else' from `else return -1;` or add a `return -2;` to see the case where your code followed none of the paths.

I see you're using GCC -- add the '-Wall' option to get maximal diagnostics from the compiler, it should tell you that your function has a code path which does not return a value.

Answer (score 3):

Nah, you've got it slightly wrong. Your last else belongs to the first if statement, so that will never be called. Your function happens to return 5 because that happens to be in the place where the compiler normally places the return value.

You can't rely on that though as it is undefined behavior as per the C++ standard section 6.6.3 (if my google skills serve me right).

Answer (score 2):

this is offtopic for this site, but lets go through each line

```
int a=5, b =3;
int c = a*b;
```

c is 15 right now

```
if(c >10) // 15>10 - true
{
    if( (a<b) && (a>0) ) // 5<3 - false, so we go further
    {
        cout <<"James";
        return a;
    }
    else if(b<0) // 3<0 - false, we go further
    {
        return b;
    }
    // here is error, should be another one return
}
else
    return -1; // this will not be executed, as it is else for if (c>10)
```

update: why it returns 5 - usually return value of function is placed into (e)ax register (I assume you're on x86 platform), so your compiler used ax for storing value of a during comparison

Comment: @GManNickG question "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved", if OP didn't even try to debug code - this is not minimal understanding, I can say that no any kind of analytic/debug work was done here at all

Answer (score 0):

If you exit a function that returns `int` without `return` ing a value, the result is undefined.  Not a default value.

The compiler could print 5, could print 0, coukd print 4232732, or it could format your hard drive.  All woukd be legal C++ results of your program.

The way to handle this is two fold: turn on warnings and warnings as errors, as there is most definitely a wsrning for not all control paths returning a value.

Second, do not make functions where not all control paths return a value.